# Criando Annotations customizado em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Possuo um `Controller` em meu projeto [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) (Web Service) que preciso fazer uma verificação de token para requisição de cada método. Uma solução que encontrei é criar um método estático e colocar uma chamada a cada começo de cada método. Eu poderia colocar apenas uma vez no construtor do meu `Controller` mas esse é o problema: nem todos os métodos precisam dessa verificação.

Então gostaria de saber como implementar um Annotations com a implementação da minha verificação e usar o Annotations para validar essas requisições. Caso a requisição for inválida, a requisição é remetida para uma página 404.

Gostaria de um horizonte de como fazer isto, algo como esse pseudo-código abaixo:

```
@VerificationToken
public List<Produto> getAllProducts(){
  // implementação
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução para isso, seria criar sua `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` herdando de `AuthorizeAttribute`

Imagine por exemplo algo como `AuthorizeByMe`

ficaria assim:

```
  public class AuthorizeByMeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

      protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
      {
          return true;           
      }
  }
```

e na action/controller

```
    [AuthorizeByMe]
    public ActionResult Skol()
    {
        //...
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer não é bem uma autenticação. É tipo uma validação customizada de token. Derivar o `[Authorize]` funcionaria bem se o projeto dele não fosse um Web Service.

Comment: Não tenho certeza do tipo do projeto, pois a questão menciona um redirecionamento para uma página 404, o que faz pouco sentido para um web-service.

Comment: Só seria válido se no retorno do Web-Service fosse uma call para uma página, e no retorno quando inválido viesse o pedido para a 404

Comment: Miguel Ângelo eu mencionei um retorno 404 mas não necessariamente deve ser 404, pode ser um retorno json customizado informando o cliente que a autenticação via token falhou.

Answer (score 3):

Em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), chamamos "Annotations" de **Attributes**. Assim como os *annotations* de [java](/questions/tagged/java), *Attributes* servem para decorar classes, métodos, propriedades, etc.

Só que um *Attribute* é uma classe especial que precisa ser chamada por outra pra funcionar. No seu caso, o que você quer é chamar o método, mas antes disso, que seja testada uma condição antes do método. Isso se faz [implementando um Proxy Dinâmico](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5511/Dynamic-Proxy-Creation-Using-C-Emit), fazendo um `override` no método `Invoke` dessa classe de Proxy.

Pretendo colocar uma solução mais completa em breve. Estou inclusive favoritando a questão para voltar nela depois. Em todo caso, você pode usar a solução do @tchicotti e derivar o `[Authorize]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Pode criar um interceptor. O método "InvokeAsync" será sempre chamado antes do seus métodos no controller:**

```cs
 {
    public class MyInterceptor
    {
        public readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyInterceptor(RequestDelegate next) : base (next) { }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            < seu código >

            await _next(context);

            < seu código >
        }
    }

    public static class MyInterceptorExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyInterceptor(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyInterceptor>();
        }
    }
```

**Para registrar o interceptor, altere o arquivo Program.cs:**

```cs
app.UseMyInterceptor();
```